# ArcGIS Server Tiles as Basemap in CartoDB

Tags: arcgis-server, tiles, carto, basemap, url

Has anyone successfully used their ArcGIS Server Tilecache as a CartoDB Basemap?  I'm trying to hit mine directly using the XYZ Tile URL Template as follows:

http://mercator10.library.yale.edu/ArcGIS/rest/services/Digital_New_Haven/Atlas_of_New_Haven_1911_Mosaic/MapServer/tile/{z}/{x}/{y}

without success. I'm probably missing something obvious.

Comment: what version of ArcServer?

Comment: Looks like you're on 10.0.  At 10.2, you can deliver WMTS which CartoDB appears to support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately ESRI decided to use his own tiling scheme with ArcGIS Online. Now they are going back to use the normal web mercator tiling Google and everybody else is using. But probably for older versions it is not available.
On the new ArcGIS Online they have started to replace all services with the normal tiling system.

Check out for example:

http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2010/12/29/use-arcgis-online-web-mercator-map-services-for-most-current-data/

So, unfortunately I dont think is possible to use that service directly as a Tiling service. Will keep checking.

Answer (score 2):

You can use directly the WMS url in the 'add new basemap' modal window.
[Here](http://blog.cartodb.com/post/67460068881/cartodb-makes-it-easy-to-add-the-perfect-basemap-to) is a blogpost where this is briefly explained.